# Changing an Array format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, stringify

I have an array as below

```
    [
      {
        CRT_FIRST_NAME: 'Shekhar',
        CRT_MIDDLE_NAME: 'Kumar'
      },
      {
        CRT_FIRST_NAME: 'Sameer',
        CRT_MIDDLE_NAME: 'Kumar'
      },
      {
        CRT_FIRST_NAME: 'Martin',
        CRT_MIDDLE_NAME: undefined
      }
    ]
```

to the below format. i.e, I want to have `double quotes` for both keys and values. I tried `JSON.stringify`  but it is giving me errors

```
 [
      {
        "CRT_FIRST_NAME": "abc",
        "CRT_MIDDLE_NAME": "Kumar"
      },
      {
        "CRT_FIRST_NAME": "pqr",
        "CRT_MIDDLE_NAME": "Kumar"
      },
      {
        "CRT_FIRST_NAME": "sample",
        "CRT_MIDDLE_NAME": "Kumar"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? If you post the text of the error, we should be able to figure this out.

Comment: @Jacob Syntax errors. you can check here in this link https://jsfiddle.net/jt3do471/

Comment: You should post the code in your fiddle here instead. The syntax error is because of the code you've written there, not because of what you've posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: in your fiddle, you wrapped the whole array `([...])` in `var jsonData = "..."` - you can't do that. Remove the string wrapper and call `JSON.stringify(...)` directly on the array.